# C++: How to pipe from a file to cin and display as if user typed the input

Tags: c++, bash, pipe

I have a simple C++ program that uses `cin` to read eight numbers, and I'm running it in a bash shell. When I run it in the terminal, it looks like this (the user types in the numbers 1-8):

```
./add8
Please enter eight numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
The sum is: 36
```

I am trying to pipe in a file that has the eight numbers (e.g., "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" and a newline), but the input does not show on the screen:

```
./add8 < my_eight_numbers.txt
Please enter eight numbers: The sum is: 36
```

Is it possible to pipe the file into the program *and* show the input as if the user typed it?

Comment: I think you mean redirect, not pipe. From the tag wiki: *A Unix pipe connects file descriptors of two processes. A pipe is created with the POSIX pipe() function declared in <unistd.h>. Shells provide pipe creation between processes using "|".*

Comment: You can't do it with ordinary redirection. Maybe `Expect` can do it, I'm not sure.

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place to ask this. It has nothing to do with C++, because redirection is handled by the shell and is independent of the program that's reading the input.

Comment: Your program would need to detect that input has been redirected - the means to do that are system dependent - and then explicitly echo the input it receives if needed.

Comment: Input echo is a feature of the terminal session, not of the bash shell.

Comment: @Barmar Good point, will post there. Thanks.

Comment: @barmar & peter: agreed, but for the sake of user experience, we can choose to echo back the characters from C++ code, in case stdin was redirected.

Comment: You could do that, but then you'll get double echo when input is from a terminal, unless you do extra checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tee` with process substitution:

```
tee >(./add8)< my_eight_numbers.txt
```

Comment: There is an issue, (I think): the sequence of the prompt statement & the piped stdin is not fixed, because of obvious reasons... Not sure if OP really needs it so...

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [cdarke's very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32523211/841108) which could work (at least on Linux) on shells without process substitutions:

```
tee /dev/tty < my_eight_numbers.txt | ./add8
```

or

```
tee /dev/stderr < my_eight_numbers.txt | ./add8
```

See [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) & [stderr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stderr.3.html) & [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (since `/dev/stderr` is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/2`). Read also [the TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page.

You might be interested by [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) if you wanted to "simulate" a user typing on a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Crude way, works on linux. tested on ubuntu 14.04.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    int i;
    int sum=0;
    cout << "Enter 8 numbers: ";
    for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        sum += num;
        if(!isatty(fileno(stdin)))
            cout << num << " ";
    }
    if(!isatty(fileno(stdin)))
        cout << endl;

    cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I am not a cpp programmer, only coded in C recently. So, there may be code in above answer which is not cpp style.

Example:

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter 8 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  # <~~~~~ Entered manually
Sum is 36

$ seq 1 8 > test.inp

$ ./a.out < test.inp 
Enter 8 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
Sum is 36
```